# Is layout_above broken? this simple layout is driving me crazy

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

here is my code

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/BIG"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="BIG"
    android:textSize="50dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/small"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/BIG"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/BIG"
    android:text="small"
    android:textSize="10dp"

    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/small"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/small"
    android:text="small above"
    android:textSize="10dp" />
```

this is the result I am getting (actual screenshot). as you can see, an entire text view has disapeared.

[image: screenshot]

this is the result I want (edited on mspaint)

[image]

I cannot use align_bottom because of the auto padding. here is what it looks like  if I use align_bottom instead of align_Baseline(actual screenshot)

[image]

Comment: Add a android:layout_toRightOf="@id/BIG" to the third textview

Comment: Your parent element is a `RelativeLayout`, right?

Comment: @karaokyo yes it is.

Comment: @KushtrimP. it doesn't do anything

Comment: It seems like your alignBaseline messes up the calculations. Couldn't you just add another parent `LinearLayout` for your 2 small texts?

Comment: Check out 3rd post : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/M9THu9V08vo/EouuJZv1dTAJ

Comment: @karaokyo I don't understand how that would help me. I need the BIG word and small word to be bottom aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently baseline alignment is performed after all other vertical alignment has already been performed.
So *“small above”*  is lined up above *“small”*  when it is still in its default position. Then, “small” is aligned with the baseline of *“BIG”*  leaving “small above” out of view, at the top of the *RelativeLayout*.

One potential solution to this problem is to wrap the two smaller TextViews in a LinearLayout that can then be properly baseline aligned with the larger TextView on the left.
 And also add  **android:baselineAlignedChildIndex="1"**  to the LinearLayout, so that the the second child's baseline is aligned to the "BIG"

Reference: http://scottweber.com/2014/02/06/working-with-baselines-in-relativelayout/

Comment: thank you! android:baselineAlignedChildIndex="1" was the missing part of the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/BIG"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="BIg"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="small above"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="small"
        android:textSize="10sp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

and use sp instead of dp for text sizes.

Comment: I cannot use a lower case g, which is why I have to work with align_Baseline